# Static Object in UIScrollVIew

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Part of my iOS app involves a PDF Reader. To display the page the user is on, I have created a UILabel and placed it in the PDFScrollView (subclass of UIScrollView). This label has to be in the scroll view because whenever I change the page, the scroll view sends a message to the IBOutlet of the label, telling it to change its text.

However, whenever I zoom in (scroll "out") in the UIScrollView, the label zooms out as well (its size doesn't change, but it travels outwards). This causes it to eventually move off the screen. **How can I change it so the UILabel is static and unmoving in the UIScrollView?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subclassing the `UIScrollView`, subclass a `UIView` and place a `UIScrollView` and `UIView` as subviews with the `UIView` not being a subview of the scroll view. Place your label(s), etc. inside the `UIView` and have the parent view manage communication between the scroll view and the other view.

```
UIView + UIScrollView (your PDFScrollView)
+---------------------------------------+
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-                                       -
-       UIView (not a subview)          -
-       +----------------------+        -
-       -      Label(s)        -        -
-       -                      -        -
-       +----------------------+        -
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could I do ViewController->UIView->UIScrollView with all my labels in UIView?

Comment: I added a visual to explain what I mean.

Comment: So the UILabel should be a subview of a subview of the ScrollView?

Comment: No, the `UILabel` should be a subview of the `UIView` that "floats" over the `UIScrollView` (is not a subview, otherwise, it would scroll too). These two views are subviews of one big `UIView`.

Comment: You mean the default UIView of the ViewController?

Comment: I would enclose the scroll view and the other view (that contains the labels) in one `UIView` and link that as the `view` of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this as soon as I get the chance and mark your answer as correct if it works

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIScrollViewDelegate`, implement the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {

    uiLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY);
    uiLabel.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

where you calculate properly scaleX, scaleY, X, and Y.
You could try using `1.0/scrollView.zoomScale` for both `scaleX` and `scaleY`.

There is a very good tutorial on using `UIScrollView` for a view hierarchy on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) site.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Still compilation problems or simply the UILabel keeps scaling? Try using 1.0 for both scaleX and scaleY.

Comment: The UILabel keeps scaling. i tried 1.0 for each, but it didn't help.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it either